# Bind Environment Variables to Class Using IConfigurationRoot

Tags: c#, configuration, environment-variables, .net-core

In dotnet core I want to bind a set of environment variables to a class using `IConfigurationRoot` and the `Bind` method similar what you do with the `appsettings.json`

For Example

having the following `appsettings.json`

```
{
    "EnviromentSettings":
    {
        "ValueOne": "Foo1",
        "ValueTwo": "Foo2"
    }
}
```

I can bind the section `EnvimentSettings` to the following class

```
public class EnviromentSettings
{
    public string ValueOne {get;set;}
    public string ValueTwo {get;set;}
}
```

using this code

```
public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

services.Configure<EnviromentSettings>(options => Configuration.GetSection("EnviromentSettings").Bind(options));
```

Can I do something similar for environment variables?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, just remove "EnvironmentSettings" from the appsettings.json file.  This works for me.  Note: It will read from the appsettings.json file first and over-ride with environment variables, if they exist.

appsettings.json

```
{
 "ValueOne": "Foo1",
 "ValueTwo": "Foo2"
}
```

code changes

```
EnvironmentSettings settings = new EnvironmentSettings();

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("config.json")
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
config = builder.Build();

ConfigurationBinder.Bind(config, settings);

Console.WriteLine($"ValueOne: {settings.ValueOne}");
Console.WriteLine($"ValueTwo: {settings.ValueTwo}");
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that you need to add is a [simple method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration):

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    // yes, that simple
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Some notes from MSDN:

> **Configuration sources are read in the order they are specified**. In the code above, the environment variables are read last. Any configuration values set through the environment would replace those set in the two previous providers.
>
> The environment is typically set to one of `Development`, `Staging`, or `Production`. See [Working with Multiple Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments) for more information.

I suggest you to read [whole article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration) for better understanding your options.